# Primeng p-menu disable menu item programmatically based on boolean check

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an Angular 8 App where I am using `p-menu` and menu-items to display menu. I am in a situation where I need to validate the logic depends on other API. If the logic returns true then I have my local boolean variable is set to true.

Now the problem is even though the variable is set to true. I can see that in console log, when I pass this variable inside `menu items array` nothing has happened. Not sure why variable value is not taken here.

**In my component.ts:**

```
    export class AddInCommandsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
        dataModel: AuthListModel = {
            apiKey: this.configService.apiKey,
            appURL: this.configService.appUrl,
        };
        items: MenuItem[];
        noTaskFound = false;


        ngOnInit() {

         this.items = [
            {
                label: 'Resources',
                items: [

                    {
                        label: 'Import & Map Resources',
                        icon: 'ms-Icon ms-Icon--Handwriting ms-fontSize-32 ',
                        title:
                            ' Retrieves Time Writers from Tidy & Map existing resources to Tidy Time Writers',
                        command: event => this.showMapResourcesScreen(),
                        disabled: this.noTaskFound,
                    },
                ],
            },
       ];
          }
```

**Note:** In the above sample, you can see the `disabled` property is set by the local variable.

And the below is my method which has has been executed in the constructor. Log showing `this.noTaskfound = true`

```
async checkResourceExist() {
        const ResourceMaxIndex = await this.projectTaskService.getMaxResourceIndex();
        console.log('check resource exec');
        console.log('Resource MaxIndex', ResourceMaxIndex);
        if (ResourceMaxIndex === 0) {
            this.noTaskFound = true;
            console.log('no task found:', this.noTaskFound);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help how to achieve this programmatically.

Comment: disabled: checkResourceExist(), call like this.

Comment: We are not allowed to call the async method inside the property. Because getMaxResourceIndex is a promise.

Comment: make *this.items* in **ngAfterViewInit()** instead ngOnInit()

Comment: You beat me in to it. Tried that already and ngAfterContentChecked()- both fails

Comment: looks like ngAfterContentChecked() is working

Comment: oh great you, otho need to perform debug the code in all the critical places to identify the synchronous functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206556/discussion-between-saisiva-a-and-ragavan-rajan).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I ended up just putting my MenuItems in a getter, so that the disabled condition has to be interpreted each time. I can imagine performance concerns for large menus this way, but works great for small ones.

Comment: For instance, if you had this as your menuData, it would randomly set disable each time you opened the menu... just as an example. Naturally, you could disable against any property or condition:

`public get someMenuData(): MenuItem[] {
    return [{ items: [{ label: 'One', disabled: Math.random() > 0.5 }] }];
  }`

Comment: Ack... forgive the formatting mess. Let me know if you'd like a fuller version of this as a separate answer. Jist is simple... binding to the getter forces it to rebuild the menu each time against any conditions as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help someone who wants to `disable menu item` programmatically.

**Note: Use one of the Angular lifecycle event called `ngAfterContentChecked`**

Step 1: In component.ts file under export part add ngAfterContentChecked

```
export class AddInCommandsComponent
    implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentChecked {
```

And then add the relevant import

```
import {
    AfterContentChecked,
    AfterViewInit,
    ChangeDetectorRef,
    Component,
    OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
```

Step 2: In the same component.ts file

```
   ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
        this.ref.detectChanges();
        this.items = [
            {
                label: 'Resources',
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'Import & Map Resources',
                        icon: 'ms-Icon ms-Icon--Handwriting ms-fontSize-32 ',
                        title:
                            ' Retrieves Time Writers',
                        command: event => this.showMapResourcesScreen(),
                        disabled: this.noTaskFound,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                label: 'MS Project to Bamboo',
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'Create Project in Bamboo',
                        icon: 'ms-Icon ms-Icon--Export ms-fontSize-32 ',
                        title:
                            'Export all tasks from this project into a new project in Tidy',
                        command: event => this.showCreateInScreen(),
                        disabled: this.noTaskFound,
                ],
            },
            /*            {
label: 'Bamboo to MS Project',
items: [
{
label: 'Import Tasks from Bamboo',
icon: 'ms-Icon ms-Icon--Import ms-fontSize-32 ',
title:
'Import all tasks from Bamboo into a blank project',
command: event => this.showImportFromScreen(),
},
{
label: 'Update Tasks from Bamboo',
icon: 'ms-Icon ms-Icon--PostUpdate ms-fontSize-32',
title:
'Update all tasks in this project from changes made in Bamboo',
disabled: true,
},
],
},*/
        ];
    }
```

Remember: `ngAfterViewInit` will throw `Expression changed error`.

Step 3: In the constructor add the `changeDetectorRef` and the relevant import

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This approach causes my page to never render and eventually throw an error within Chrome (Page Unresponsive). Did not work for me. The line this.ref.detectChanges() refers to an instance var that you do not show here. Is it necessary?

Comment: @MikeA changeDetectorRef may require, It is worth giving try.

Comment: Just now tried it. Still hangs. Thanks for the help though. I don't understand how this is not a widespread problem.

Comment: sorry @MikeA.  I have checked the App that works really fine. It is not crashing. Sorry couldnt help exactly what else is causing problem. Would you be able to log anything in your method and post the results here.

Comment: Or if you create a stackblitz and share the link. Would definitely take a look

Answer (score 0):

My issue involves using a PrimeNG **template** which was not conducive to manipulating the menu items. This was my experience anyway.

Here is how the template renders the MenuItem[] array:

```
<div class="layout-menu-wrapper">
    <ul class="layout-menu">
       <li app-menuitem *ngFor="let item of model; let i = index;" [item]="item" [index]="i" [root]="true" [mega]="false"></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

I assumed that manipulating an entry in the MenuItem[] array would have the menu item respect that modification. This is not the case. Even if I set visible or disabled directly in the array, that still did not work.

I replaced the template html with:

```
<div class="layout-menu-wrapper">
    <ul class="layout-menu">
        <p-menubar [model]="model"></p-menubar>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the typescript code, I grabbed a hold of the menu items in an instance var and inserted those into the MenuItem[] array. Once I had a handle to those menu items, I can control them with Obervables:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu',
    templateUrl: './app.menu.component.html'
})
export class AppMenuComponent implements OnInit {

    model: MenuItem[];
    loggedIn = false;

    loginMenuItem: MenuItem = { label: 'Login', icon: 'ui-icon-verified-user', routerLink: ['/login'] };
    logoutMenuItem: MenuItem = { label: 'Logout', icon: 'ui-icon-cancel', routerLink: ['/logout'] };
    customerMenuItem: MenuItem = { label: 'Customers', icon: 'ui-icon-group', routerLink: ['/customers'] };
    ordersMenuItem: MenuItem = { label: 'Orders', icon: 'ui-icon-library-music', routerLink: ['/orders'] };
    inventoryMenuItem: MenuItem = { label: 'Inventory', icon: 'ui-icon-library-books', routerLink: ['/inventory'] };
    signUpMenuItem: MenuItem = { label: 'Sign Up', icon: 'ui-icon-group-add', routerLink: ['/sign-up'] };

    mainMenuItems = [this.customerMenuItem, this.ordersMenuItem, this.inventoryMenuItem];

    constructor(
        public app: AppMainComponent,
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private menuService: MenuService) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        // Set the initial logged in state.
        this.loginMenuItem.visible = !this.loginService.isLoggedIn();
        this.logoutMenuItem.visible = this.loginService.isLoggedIn();

        this.mainMenuItems.forEach ( (menuItem: MenuItem) => {
                menuItem.visible = this.loginService.isLoggedIn();
            }
        );

        // Listen for future logged in states.
        this.loginService.loggedInStatus$.subscribe(
            (isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
                this.loggedIn = isLoggedIn;
                this.loginMenuItem.visible = !isLoggedIn;
                this.logoutMenuItem.visible = isLoggedIn;

                this.mainMenuItems.forEach ( (menuItem: MenuItem) => {
                    menuItem.visible = isLoggedIn;
                });
            }
        );

        this.model = [
            this.customerMenuItem,
            this.ordersMenuItem,
            this.inventoryMenuItem,
            this.signUpMenuItem,
            this.loginMenuItem,
            this.logoutMenuItem,

            // These are other template sample entries.
            {
                label: 'Components', icon: 'list', // routerLink: ['/components'],
                items: [
                    {label: 'Sample Page', icon: 'desktop_mac', routerLink: ['/components/sample']},
                    {label: 'Forms', icon: 'input', routerLink: ['/components/forms']},
                    {label: 'Data', icon: 'grid_on', routerLink: ['/components/data']},
                    {label: 'Panels', icon: 'content_paste', routerLink: ['/components/panels']},
                    {label: 'Overlays', icon: 'content_copy', routerLink: ['/components/overlays']},
                    {label: 'Menus', icon: 'menu', routerLink: ['/components/menus']},
                    {label: 'Messages', icon: 'message', routerLink: ['/components/messages']},
                    {label: 'Charts', icon: 'insert_chart', routerLink: ['/components/charts']},
                    {label: 'File', icon: 'attach_file', routerLink: ['/components/file']},
                    {label: 'Misc', icon: 'toys', routerLink: ['/components/misc']}
                ]
            }
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

There may be a better way to do this, but I'm just glad that I found a way to pull this off. I would have preferred to use the PrimeNG template, but I could not control the MenuItem entries no matter what I did. The menu looks different now, but I'll have to deal with that as a separate issue.

If there is another way to pull this off, please share!